# React Native - 'Unable to resolve module error'

Tags: react-native

I am trying to learn React Native with a simple project.

This is my folder design:

[image]

I got this error:

[image]

**I want to use 'navigationBar' file in 'App.js'.**

How can I use 'navigationBar' file in 'App.js' without getting this error?

Comment: Have you tried adding .js to navigationBar  ---> navigationBar .js?

Comment: could you include package.json in post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `.js` extension to your file, such as `components/NavigationBar.js`.

React Native is very conservative about the file extensions (not exactly the same, but gives an idea on the matter : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2303).

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the address that you used to use your Navbar component inside your screen is wrong. Just put the correct address to use it. I hope it helps you. 
However for being sure about that . It would be better if you also share your App.js and your component code.